# Bootbox ASP.NET MVC Confirmations

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootbox

Hi I'm trying to get Confirm dialog (Bootbox) to work. It displays the confirmation dialog but doesn't do anything upon pressing the Ok button.

```
 $(document).on("click", "#close", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to close this Service Request? This operation cannot be reversed."
                , function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        $this.closest('form').submit();
                    } else {
                        console.log("user declined");
                    }
                });
        });
```

I believe this is wrong:

```
$this.closest('form').submit();
```

My button is `<td><a href="@Url.Action("CloseLog", "Log", new {id = item.LogID})"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" id="close"></span></a>`

Question is how do I get the ok button to work?

EDIT: 
Can I call this function from onClick in button? If so How?

```
$(document).on("click", ".alert", function (e) {
            var link = $(this).attr("href"); // "get" the intended link in a var
            e.preventDefault();
            bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    document.location.href = link;  // if result, "set" the document location      
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: do you mean that nothing happens after you press the ok?

Comment: exactly. nothing happens

Comment: $ is a meta sign, don't use it a as a part of variable name, try $(this).closest('form').submit();

Comment: Please see my question edit @VladL

Comment: Or how would I use it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#close").click(function()
  {
     var link = $(this).attr("href"); // "get" the intended link in a var
     var result = confirm("Are you sure?");
     if(result)
     {
       document.location.href = link;  // if result, "set" the document location      
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry didn't work. It doesn't show any dialog at all and just goes ahead with the delete

Comment: Do I need to change my button/link in any way?

Comment: @ASPCoder1450 and now?

Comment: now it just shows a standard javascript confirm dialog and not bootbox

Comment: @ASPCoder1450 well I don't really know what do you have and what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to acheive Bootbox confirmations. In essence I want to replace the standard JS confirm boxes with those of bootbox

Comment: @ASPCoder1450 to be honest I've never heard about the bootbox so not sure about it's syntax